# Query related to constructors in inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

I have a question related to inherotance.

I declare a class and then declare a child class as below

```
`Producer::Producer(Pool<string>* p, string id) {
    mPool = p;  // protected members
    mId = id;
}

ProduceCond::ProduceCond(Pool<string>* p, string id) {
    Producer(p, id);
}

class Producer{
}

class ProduceCond : public Producer, public ThreadSubject {
}
```

`

Though I have called right parent constructor in the child constructor I receive an error

```
ProduceCond.cpp:10:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘Producer::Producer()’
```

Can someone tell me why I receive this error although I use correct constructor format of the parent?

Comment: You probably need a default constructor for `Producer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *initialize sub-object(base) which has no default constructor*, you need to call it through member initializer list:

```
ProduceCond::ProduceCond(Pool<string>* p, string id) : Producer(p, id) {}
```

Or you could provide a default constructor which will be called implicitly by sub-class constructor

```
Producer() : mPool(std::nullptr) { }
```

Also you have to use member initializer in below conditions:

```
1 You must (at least, in pre-C++11) use this form to initialize a nonstatic const data
member.

2 You must use this form to initialize a reference data member.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. I guess you had posted some links in above answer which arent working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the constructor initialization list:

```
ProduceCond::ProduceCond(Pool<string>* p, string id)  : Producer(p, id)
{
  ....
}
```

Otherwise, you are default constructing a `Producer` (which you can't, because it has no default constructor), then doing something strange in the body of the constructor.

Comment: So If i dont use a constructor list, its not possible to call the parent constructor from body of the child constructor, right?

Comment: @tariqzafar No, by the time you get to the body of the derived class' constructor, the base class' sub-object has already been constructed.